# Android Camera activity takes time to render

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have a simple app.On Button click from the Main activity,I call another activity which just shows a preview from the front Camera.I observe that it takes around 4 seconds for the second activity to launch.I think its because of the time it takes to render the camera preview element in the second activity.This is way too long and I am looking for a way to reduce the rendering time of the second activity.Here is my code:

**Main.java**:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnLaunchCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.launchCamera);
        btnLaunchCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Cam.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Cam.java**

```
public class Cam extends Activity {

    private static int cameraId = 0;
    private Camera camera;

    //Adding for camera preview
    public static FrameLayout preview;
    public static CameraPreview mPreview;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.e("Cam","Inside onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.cam);
        context = getApplicationContext();

        // Do we have a camera?
        try {
            if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                cameraId = AppFunctions.findFrontFacingCamera();
                if (cameraId < 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    try {
                        camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                        Log.d("Cam","camera id" + cameraId);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);
                        preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
                        preview.addView(mPreview);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.e("Cam","Inside onPause");
        try {
            if (camera != null) {
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
                preview.removeView(mPreview);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("Cam","Inside onResume");
        try {
            if(camera ==null) {
                Log.d("Cam","in resume,camera is  null");
                try {
                    camera = android.hardware.Camera.open(cameraId);                
                    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);
                    preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
                    preview.addView(mPreview);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("Cam","Inside onDestroy");
        if (camera != null) {
            try {
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
                preview.removeView(mPreview);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**cam.xml**

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="453dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:padding="5dp" >
    </FrameLayout>
```

**CameraPreview.java**

```
    /** A basic Camera preview class */
    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;
        final static String TAG = "CameraPreview";

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);

            try {
                mCamera = camera;
                mHolder = getHolder();
                mHolder.addCallback(this);
                mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Inside SurfaceDestroyed");
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }

            // stop preview before making changes
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
            }

            // start preview with new settings
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Please assist me on how I can reduce the rendering time for the second activity.Any help would be appreciated.Many thanks !

Comment: The issue is that you are running the camera.open() command on the apps main UI thread. You would get better results by putting that command, and most other camera commands in a separate thread and running them all them.